# Сортировка чисел по сумме цифр в дробной части

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Требуется создать файл из n вещественных чисел и отсортировать его элементы по сумме цифр в дробной части, а результат сохранить в другом файле. Получилось только написать сортировку дробных чисел по целой части. Код прилагаю ниже:

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream fin("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\chisla.txt");
    ofstream fout("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\chisla1.txt");
    double n;
    vector<double> v;
    if (fin) {
        while (fin >> n && n) {
            v.push_back(n);
        }
        sort(v.begin(), v.end());
        fout << "Output of the program:\n";
        for (double i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            fout << v[i] << " ";
        }
    } else {
        cout << "No file input.txt found!\n";
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу довести задачу до конца. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А вы ее и не начинали... Как совет - не читайте числа как `double` - потом будут проблемы с цифрами в дробной части. Читайте как строки.